# How to load image data by keys in keras?

Tags: keras

I've been working on a sequential model which takes images as inputs. However, different thing is that the input images are actually determined by keys.
For example, the training sequence is (You may assume *fi* is frame id of a video)

```
{ f1, f2, f3, ..., fn }
```

and the corresponding image sequence is

```
{ M[f1], M[f2], M[f3], ..., M[fn] }
```

where M is a map storing {*fi->image*} mapping.
Suppose in the next batch, my training sequence become

```
{ f2, f3, ..., fn+1 }
```

and the image sequence becomes

```
{ M[f2], M[f3], M[f4], ..., M[fn+1] }
```

As you can see, if I directly save the image sequences into disk, there are lot of redundancies (in the above case, M[f2] to M[fn] are saved twice). So it seems necessary that the images are referenced by keys and thus imagedataloader class can not be used.
[**EDIT**]
My model is a **2-class** classifier takes image sequences as input, in which the images are mapped with the *frame id*(*fi*). Whether an image sequence is positive or negative is pre-generated in my *data_preprocess* code.
**Positive** samples may look like this:

```
{f3,  f4,  f5,  f6,  f7}     1
{f4,  f5,  f6,  f7,  f8}     1
{f5,  f6,  f7,  f8,  f9}     1
...
```

While **negative** samples look like this:

```
{f1,  f2,  f3,  f4,  f5}     0
{f2,  f3,  f4,  f5,  f6}     0
{f10, f11, f12, f13, f14}    0
...
```

So, it is not like image classifying problem, where an image has exactly a fixed label. In my case, every image will be used many times and their being positive or negative are together determined by the whole sequence, but not itself.
[**EDIT II**]
The images are frames of N videos and are stored on disk like this:

```
|-data_root/
  |-Video 1/
  | |-frame_1_1.jpg
  | |-frame_1_2.jpg
  | ...
  |-Video 2/
  | |-frame_2_1.jpg
  | |-frame_2_2.jpg
  | ...
  ...
  ...
  |-Video N/
  | |-frame_N_1.jpg
  | |-frame_N_2.jpg
    ...
```

What I'd like to do is, given two sequences of frames/images of scenes, the model predicts whether the two scenes are of the same kind.
Since a video may contain a long time span for each scene, I divide the whole sequence of a scene into a number of non-overlap sub-sequences (omit the indexes of videos):

```
Sequence of scene i: frame_1,  frame_2,  frame_3,  ..., frame_n
Sub-sequence i_1:    frame_1,  frame_2,  frame_3,  ..., frame_10
Sub-sequence i_2:    frame_11, frame_12, frame_13, ..., frame_20
Sub-sequence i_3:    frame_21, frame_22, frame_23, ..., frame_30
...
```

Then, I randomly generate positive samples Pi (pairs of sub-sequences generated from the **same** sequence), like:

```
   <Pair of sub-sequences>                 <Labels>
P1 {sub-sequence i_4, sub-sequence i_2},      1
P2 {sub-sequence i_3, sub-sequence i_5},      1
...                                       ...
```

For negative samples, I generate pairs of sub-sequences (Ni) from **different** scenes:

```
   <Pair of sub-sequences>                 <Labels>
N1 {sub-sequence i_1, sub-sequence j_6},      0
N2 {sub-sequence i_2, sub-sequence j_4},      0
...                                       ...
```

It is obvious that one frame/image can occur multiple times in different training samples. E.g. in the above case, both N2 and P1 contain sub-sequence i_2. So I choose to save the generated sample pairs by sequences of frame id(**fi**) and during training, fetch the corresponding frames/images of a sequence by frame id(**fi**).
How should I do it elegantly with Keras?

Comment: You can do a lot for the value of your question by breaking thoughts into paragraphs (simply two newlines). You can also surround bits of code with Graves (apostrophe-like key next to the 1) `like this`. Blocks of code can be shown with two newlines and each line indented with four spaces.

Comment: Do this images sequences always have this form of sequential indeces or it's possible to have indeces like `f1, f3, f2, f5`? How are they stored on disk? What is the structure of your directory? How this preprocessing function used for labeling data looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you build your sequences but have you considered using the [`ImageDataGenerator` from `keras.preprocessing.image`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) ?

Once you have built this object with whatever parameters  you want, you can use the `flow_from_directory(directory_path)` method. Once you have done this, you can use the filename attribute of this object :

```
my_generator = ImageDataGenerator(...)
my_generator.flow_from_directory(path_dir)
list_of_file_names = my_generator.filename
```

you now have a mapping between indexes of the list and the elements(=file_paths) of the list.

I hope this helps?

**EDIT :**

From this, you can build a mapping a dictionnary

```
map_images = {str(os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file_path)[1])[0]): file_path for file_path in list_of_file_names}
```

This takes the `file_path` retrieved from you image folder using ImageDataGenerator, it extracts the file name, removes the file extension and transforms the name of the file into an `string` which is your frame_id.

You now have a map between `frame_id` and `file_path` that you can use with [`load_img()` and `img_to_array()` from `keras.preprocessing.image`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

the function `load_img()` is defined like this and returns a PIL image instance:

> `def load_img(path, grayscale=False, target_size=None):
>       """Loads an image into PIL format.
>       # Arguments
>           path: Path to image file
>           grayscale: Boolean, whether to load the image as grayscale.
>           target_size: Either 'None' (default to original size)
>               or tuple of ints '(img_height, img_width)'.
>       # Returns
>           A PIL Image instance.
>       # Raises
>           ImportError: if PIL is not available.
>       """`

Then `img_to_array()` is defined like this and returns a 3D numpy array to feed your model:

> `def img_to_array(img, dim_ordering='default'):
>       """Converts a PIL Image instance to a Numpy array.
>       # Arguments
>           img: PIL Image instance.
>           dim_ordering: Image data format.
>       # Returns
>           A 3D Numpy array.
>       # Raises
>           ValueError: if invalid 'img' or 'dim_ordering' is passed.
>       """`

So to summarize : 1 build a mapping between your frame_id and the path of the corresponding file. Then load the file using `img_load()` and `img_to_array()`. I hope I have understood your question correctly !

**EDIT 2:**

Seeing your new edit, now that I understand the structure of your file system, we can even add the video in your dictionary like this :

```
# list of video_id of each frame
videos = my_generator.classes
# mapping of the frame_id to path_of_file and vid_id
map_images = {str(os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file_path)[1])[0]): (file_path, vid_id) for file_path,vid_id in zip(list_of_file_names,videos) }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I've edited my question. I hope I've made my issue clear.  As you can see, the same image may be used many times during training and the label of sequence contains it may be positive or negative. So, to save space, the generated sequences are actually made up of frame ids. With the frame id, I can use a key(id)->value(image) map to fetch the corresponding image.

Comment: My question was more around : how do you know which id must go where? Are the names of the files in your folder ordered?

Comment: Yes, the images are saved inorder and their filenames are exactly frame id. E.g. 123.jpg 124.jpg ...

Comment: alright then, I think you can do it with what I gave you but I need to be clearer. I'll try to explain the hack

Comment: Hello Ben, I've again updated my question. Wonder if I've made it clearer?

Comment: Wow that's a fast and nice answer! Really thanks! :)

Comment: If it doesnt fit your need I think you now have the tools to load your images ;)

Comment: Actually my task is a little bit more complex than my description, but this is almost near and inspirational.

Comment: Hi, Ben~ Sorry for bothering you, but I'm not sure if I must do the normalization manually for images when I fetch them by keys during training? Or should I implement a class like ImageDataGenerator which can pass preprocessed data to the model?

Comment: Look up ImageDataGenerator in Keras documentation, it can normalize and do most of the preprocessing automatically :-)